# Podcast listening app that lets rate episodes or keep notes?

Tags: android, podcast

I need it for Android. Seeing public ratings is a plus too.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Stitcher Radio, this is more of a freemium app that you could pay to not hear ads. This is a multiplatform app that you could listen via web on your desktop, Amazon Alexa, iOS, and Android.
https://www.stitcher.com/